# Most of my files are being copied to the root of my home directory

Tags: partitioning, files, filesystem, home-directory, 18.10

The `/home` directory is on a 500GB SSD, with Documents, Pictures, etc. (currently residing on the 4TB HDD) symlinked to my `/home`.  For some reason, right after I logged in, the files have been moved to the root of my home directory.

It seems to have affected only my Documents, Pictures, Videos & Music directories. My Downloads & other directories that weren't created by default, such as my Projects and Games directories, haven't been touched.

Edit: I think I see what the problem is now

```
$ cat .config/user-dirs.dirs 
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run.
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
# 
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/"
```

Thought it'd be fine with symlinks.  Well, it should be fine because Downloads wasn't affected.  Gonna fix that and see what happens.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the contents of your `.config/user-dirs.dirs` directory (`cat ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`)

Comment: If I understand it correctly you want to move `SSD/home/YOU/Documents` to `HDD/YOU/Documents`, `/SSD/home/YOU/Pictures` to `HDD/YOU/Pictures`, etc? If so can you copy and past the output from `lsblk` into your question?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I actually don't.  I don't need anything moved.  Files from `/home/WDB4T/YOU/{Documents,Pictures,Videos,Music}` (my HDD) have been moved to the root of the home directory on my SSD (`/home/YOU`).  I didn't want them moved.  It just did by itself.

Comment: @YamiYukiSenpai were they moved from your HDD to your SSD or were they copied?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix moved

Comment: @steeldriver I think I solved it.